# string not recognised as a list name

Tags: python, list

I have a list with a name:

```
list_123_456 = [1,2,3]
```

I then use some parts of a filename to recreate the name of this list:

```
name = 'list_{0}_{1}' .format(filename[0:3],filename[6:9])
```

This works to the extent that 'name' now equals 'list_123_456' as I wanted it to. But the code is treating it as a string rather than as a list that I defined at the beginning.

For example, if I try:

```
len(name)
```

I get the answer '12' (letters in the name) rather that '3' that I would like.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: That's because `name` is a string. You might want to get the object associated with that variable name, possibly with the use of `eval`, which is not recommended

Comment: I found 11 independent dups last time I looked, and each one of them links to several others…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is almost always a bad idea. If you just create a dictionary, instead of a bunch of separate variables, this is trivial:

```
lists = {}
lists[('123', '456')] = [1, 2, 3]
# ...
```

Now, instead of this:

```
name = 'list_{0}_{1}' .format(filename[0:3],filename[6:9])
```

… you can just do this:

```
name = lists[(filename[0:3], filename[6:9])]
```

You could of course key the dictionary off `'list_123_456'` instead of `('123', '456')`, or use a two-level nested dict so you can write `lists[filename[0:3]][filename[6:9]]`… whatever you find most readable.

---

If you really, really want to do this anyway, you can look up a variable name to get its value if you know the scope you want to evaluate it in, because `globals()`, `locals()`, `MyClass.__dict__`, etc. are always accessible, and they're dictionaries. So:

```
name_name = 'list_{0}_{1}' .format(filename[0:3],filename[6:9])
name = globals()[name_name]
```

If worst comes to worst, you can even `eval(name_name)`. But that's an even worse idea.

---

See [this blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your the list by name using [locals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) dictionary:

```
>>> list_123_456 = [1,2,3]
>>> locals()['list_123_456']
[1, 2, 3]
```

But this is not a good practice. Instead consider making a dictionary with mapping list names with actual lists:

```
>>> data = {'list_123_456': list_123_456}
>>> data['list_123_456']
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

> But the code is treating it as a string rather than as a list that I defined at the beginning.

That's because it is a string. Strings are not interchangeable with variables (as they are commonly called, although "name" is also a good term).

In general, if you want to look up a piece of data using a computed name (i.e. a string), you should store it in a `dict`:

```
byname = {'list_123_456':[1,2,3]}
byname[name] #=> [1,2,3]
```